# Can I assign test result to a boolean variable in Java?

Tags: java, syntax, boolean

When I write `boolean bool = aString.indexOf(subString) != -1` Eclipse did not complain, does it mean that it is the same as `boolean bool = aString.indexOf(subString) != -1 ? true : false`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. A comparison produces a boolean value, and it can be assigned to a variable just as any other value.

The second form (with the ternary `?:` operator) is redundant and should not be used.

Stylistically, I normally enclose boolean expressions in parentheses when assigning them to values, as

```
boolean bool = (aString.indexOf(subString) != -1);
```

in order to make a strong visual distinction between the two operators using the `=` symbol, but this is not required.

Answer (score 2):

Yes both syntax are equivalent.

Just use parenthesis to be clear or more readable.

```
boolean bool = (aString.indexOf(subString) != -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes certainly. A boolean expression returns a boolean value. That's why it can be used in `if` statements and so on because they expect `true` or `false` outcomes.